# Sendkeys not working on search inputfield

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to access an input field with a dynamically changing ID, and using other ways to find the element doesn't seem to work either.

This is the input field:

```
<input data-v-44dd203d="" type="search" placeholder="Search users" class="form-control form-control-md" inputmode="search" id="__BVID__27">
```

This is my current code in Java:

```
driver.get("website");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='search']")).sendKeys("name");
```

I am not getting any error, but when i am running the code, the website opens but nothing happens to the field. Seems i cannot access it, if it makes sense.

Comment: Could you please add more details of your issue? When you say sendkeys is not working, what error are you getting?

Comment: Yes of course, i am not getting any error, but when i am running the code, the website opens but nothing happens to the field. Seems i cannot access it, if it makes sense

Comment: In that case, could you please share a bit more of the source code for the page you are trying to work on? That may help the community to support you better. One thing worth checking on your page is that, whether your input field is inside an iframe. If yes, you may want to switch to it first before accessing the input field.

Comment: The input is inside a fieldset. I just tried ctrl + F to find the element using the xpath and it does highlight the input field, so now i am certain i found the right path, but unsure as to why i can't use sendkeys on it.

Comment: Thank You @Magnus Thomsen for that. But I am not sure, if can be of any more help without seeing a bit more of the html page source

Comment: Thanks for helping! I ended up finding the error. I tried accessing the input before it loaded, so i fixed it using fluentWait.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue once and adding a click to the element first and then send keys worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.